Upload file from local to second remote server through another remote server
I have a remote server that can only be accessed from an intermediate server
ssh -p 22222 user@intermediate

then I can run this:
ssh destination

How can I upload file or directory from my local machine to destination server

Using scp or rsync. Check this thread https://superuser.com/q/276533.
